# How to send an array from node.js application to JS file attached to a HTML page and then do the processing on the array?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, express

I am creating a node.js application. I need to implement the following functionality. I have 2 dropdown menus in HTML.

1. For first drop down menu I want to send an array from node.js application to the javascript file and fill the dropdown menu in the HTML.
2. For second drop down menu I want to send the value chosen from the first dropdown menu to node.js and then query the database, prepare the array and repeat the process in option 1.
   So far I know how to query the database and once i have the array in my javascript file attached to the HTML I am able to populate the HTML dropdown.
   I know how to pass the array as a variable to the HTML but i want to send the array to the javascript file attached to the HTML.

This is the html code for the two dropdowns.

```
<select class="country" name="country" required>
          <option disabled selected>Choose Country</option>
          <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="USA">USA</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <select class="province" name="province" required>
          <option disabled selected>Choose Province</option>
          <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="USA">USA</option>
        </select>
```

instead of filling up the dropdown using option values in HTML i want to take a variable from node.js server code. I know that I can pass a variable from server code to HTML but instead of receiving the variable in HTML i want to receive the array variable in Javascript code and process in the following manner.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    //init data
    var arrayList
    //variable array from node.js server code. I want to receive the variable 
    //array here rather than in HTML and make the changes in the following manner
    
        for (var i = 0; i <= arrayList.length; i++)
        {
            $('.dropdown_university').append('<option value="' + arrayList[i].Id + '">' + arrayList[i].Name + '</option>');
```

This is the node.js server side code

```
app.post("/add_new",function (req,res) {
 
  var country_array=[];//This array is filled from database. I want to send this array to javascript code.
  
});

            }
        
        });
```

Comment: NodeJS always runs in the context of some request made by the browser. So I expect you should return the data in the response to the relevant request. Without any more specifics about how your app and code is set up we can't give you much more detail than that.

Comment: @ADyson Hey, I have added some code to explain how the code is setup and what i exactly want. Can you have a go again. Thanks